# CI / CD and repository integration for Azure ML Workspace

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am interested in knowing how can I integrate a repository with Azure Machine Learning Workspace.

### What have I tried ?

I have some experience with Azure Data Factory and usually I have setup workflows where

1. I have a `dev` azure data factory instance that is linked to azure repository.
2. Changes made to the repository using the code editor.
3. These changes are published via the `adf_publish` branch to the live `dev` instance
4. I use CI / CD pipeline and the AzureRMTemplate task to deploy the templates in the publish branch to release the changes to `production` environment

### Question:

- How can I achieve the same / similar workflow with Azure Machine Learning Workspace ?
- How is CI / CD done with Azure ML Workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following workflow is the official practice to be followed to achieve the task required.

1. Starting with the architecture mentioned below

[image]

- we need to have a specific data store to handle the dataset
- Perform the regular code modifications using the IDE like Jupyter Notebook or VS Code
- Train and test the model
- To register and operate on the model, deploy the model image as a web service and operate the rest.

2. **Configure the CI Pipeline:**

- Follow the below steps to complete the procedure

  **Before implementation:**

  ```
  - We need azure subscription enabled account
  - DevOps activation must be activated.
  ```
- Open DevOps portal with enabled SSO
- Navigate to **Pipeline -> Builds -> Choose the model which was created -> Click on EDIT**
  [image]
- Build pipeline will be looking like below screen
  [image]
- We need to use Anaconda distribution for this example to get all the dependencies.
- To install environment dependencies, check the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/conda-environment?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=azdevops)
- Use the python environment, under **Install Requirements** in user setup.
- Select **create or get workspace** select your account subscription as mentioned in below screen

[image]

- Save the changes happened in other tasks and all those muse be in same subscription.
  [image]

The entire CI/CD procedure and solution was documented in [link](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/aml/#author-praneet-singh-solanki)

**Document Credit: Praneet Singh Solanki**

Comment: ok. I was under the impression that the data source / data set would be stored in some shape of JSON configuration .. somewhat like azure data factory linkedServices or datasets. But this seems NOT the case, and the direction seems to be to have a Notebook define these components and run the notebook as part of the CI / CD pipeline.. Am I getting this right ?